# How to get a value from Firebase Database and assign it to a value in Firebase Cloud Functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

So I'm using firebase as a backend to a demo app, and I like the stack quite a bit, but I'm hung up on one issue, I can't figure out how to retrieve values from the database (I've got keys just fine). 
Simply put, I'm sending information from one device that contains the "friendly-name" of another device it is trying to reach to a firebase function.
The function code looks like this:

```
exports.connectMe = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, () => {
    admin.database().ref('calls/' + req.body.id + '/').set({
        target: req.body.target,
        caller: req.body.caller,
        time: req.body.time
    });

    const target = req.body.target;
    console.log(`target: ${target}`);
    const targetCall = admin.database().ref(`tokens/${target}/token`);
    console.log(targetCall);
    // const targetValue = targetCall.val();
    res.status(200).send("Thanks For The Call!");
    });    
});
```

The variable, targetCall is correctly pointed at the db entry that I want to reach, but I cannot extract the value for the life of me. The token located at `admin.database.ref` is required to be placed in a http request. How do I get the value? The commented out code shows the variable I would want to store it in, but I know that .val() is not a method of reference.
 For the record, `admin` is set to `require('firebase-admin');` earlier in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close to getting the database query to work.

Take a look at the [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data). It explains how to access the structured data.

```
exports.connectMe = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, () => {
        const callRef = admin.database().ref('calls/' + req.body.id + '/').set({
            target: req.body.target,
            caller: req.body.caller,
            time: req.body.time
        });

        const target = req.body.target;
        console.log(`target: ${target}`);

        const takenRef = admin.database().ref(`tokens/${target}/token`)
            .once('value');

        Promise.all([callRef, takenRef])
            .then(results => {
                const snapshot = results[1]; // Promise of `takenRef`
                console.log(snapshot.val()); // This is the data from the database...

                res.status(200).send("Thanks For The Call!");
            });
    });    
});
```

See the updated code, I've added `.once('value').then(snapshot` onto your query which gives you access to the data.

Comment: That got it working just as I wanted. I didn't understand that .once('value') was meant for more than initialization, thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: Don't forget to wait for both async ops here! You could end up in a race condition and get inconsistent results. Promise.all(...) for the win.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the function `once()`, as found in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-reading-once):

```
targetCall.once("value", function(data) {
  const targetValue = data.val();
  res.status(200).send("Thanks For The Call!");
});
```